# Where is the verse "rakshasah kalim ashritya" found?

Tags: identification-request, varaha-purana

In the 10th chapter of [Jaiva Dharma](http://web.archive.org/web/20150703055304/http://nitaaiveda.com/All_Scriptures_By_Acharyas/Bhaktivinoda_Thakura/Jaiva_Dharma/Chapter-10.htm) by BhaktiVinod Thakur, a verse from Varaha Purana is quoted.

> raksasah kalim asritya jayante brahma yonisu
>
> In the Kali-yuga demons take birth in the families of the brahmanas.

Where is the verse found in Varaha Purana?

Comment: You should probably add the full verse and its translation from [here](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shri-gaudiya-kanthahara/d/doc82212.html). The same link also says its sourced from 'Cb. Ādi 11.298' so that maybe the actual source and not Varaha Purana.

Comment: @sv. I checked the Chaitanya Bhagavata. It is written in Bengali and whenever there is a sanskrit verse, it is most likely a quotation from some purana. The commentary of BhaktiSiddhanta sarasvati reads as "This verse was spoken by Lord Siva in the Varaha Purana"

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I found this verse which is somewhat related to your given verse.